# Figure cut in R-markdown and RStudio

Tags: python, r, rstudio, r-markdown

I'm working with python (and to a smaller extent with R) in RStudio in a Rmd file. However, in some cases, my figures are too big and when output below the code chunks they are cut out.

Is there a way to increase the size of the space below a code chunk that is given for a figure? Note that I'm asking on the Rmd file, **and not on the rendered HTML.**

I have tried to add

````
    ```{python fig.height=30, fig.width=30}
    [some code]
    ```
````

but this didn't solve the problem.

Note that If I press to show it as a pop-up window the full figure is there, just not directly below the code chunk in the Rmd script.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The default units for figure size are inches, I believe.  Have you tried other values or units?  eg `'30%'`?

Comment: the same happens. The figure is always cut short below the code chunk in the markdown file.

Comment: @Limey let me note that the figure is only cut short within the Rmd. If I press to show it as a pop-up window, the full figure is there.